# C# - Displaying files in DataGridView after selecting it from FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datagridview

I am trying to code a windows form application with visual studio that uses an XML file to read with LINQ. So far, I managed to Browse folders using FolderBrowserDialog and display the path in a textbox.

Now I want to read the path of folders from XML file using LINQ in my program, after selecting a folder in FolderBrowserDialog, show subfiles and subfolders of that folder in DataGridView (only name,size and path).

My XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Info>
 <Hour>10</Hour>
 <Folder>C:\Test</Folder>
</Info>
```

I managed to read Hour value but I could not reach and use Folder because I don't know how to reach path in XML file using LINQ. I tried to do something like this but I could not manage how to continue:

```
var _query2 = from p in document.Descendants("Folder")
              select p;
```

After this, I want to show name, size and type of subfiles in a DataGridView, I wrote this class but could not manage where to begin.

```
public class Info
    {
        public string name;
        public char type;
        public float size;

        public List<string> IGrid //hold information of folder's size, name, type
        {
            get {return IGrid;}
        }
        public Info (string _name, char _type, float _size)
        {
            name = _name;
            type = _type;
            size = _size;
        }

    }
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();` for reading xml files.

pass the file name to `XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(streFileName);`

use `XmlValidatingReader xmlValidatingReader = new XmlValidatingReader(xmlReader);` for validating xml and reading.

go for `linq` or `lambda` expressions like

```
xmlDoc.SelectNodes("specify the parent node").Cast<'XmlNode>().Where(x => x.Name == "check for condition").Select(x => x.InnerText);
```

I think this will help to read the file.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. How XmlValidatingReader helps me to read that directory in this problem? And I could not success the 4th solution you wrote, SelectNodes("") does not come.

Comment: solved problem using XDocument.Load(@"path") and declare path as string. thanks for reply.